# How to change the font for hyperlinks in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

For a report I am writing recently in R Markdown, I would like to change the font for the links I put on the References section. The desired output I would like to have is like the below image;

[image]

My YAML front I am using to produce the R markdown document as like the following;

```
---
title: ""
author:
  - AAA
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
geometry: "left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm"
fontsize: 12 pt
header-includes:
    - \usepackage {ragged2e}
    - \usepackage {titling}
    - \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{sectsty}
    - \usepackage{paralist}
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \usepackage{lastpage}
    - \usepackage{dcolumn}
    - \usepackage{natbib}
    - \usepackage{subcaption}
    - \usepackage{rotating}
    - \usepackage{placeins}
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \floatplacement{figure}{H}
link-citations: true
link-color: red
urlcolor: blue
biblio-style: apsr
linestretch: 2
ident: True
bibliography: ["aaa.bib"]
---
```

Therefore, I appreciate any comment or suggestion in changing the font type for the hyperlinks in the references section. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] including a bib file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

One way could be using `\urlstyle` from `url` package. From the [manual](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf) of the `url` package - section 3,

> You can switch the style of printing using “\urlstyle{xx}”, where “xx” can be
> any defined style. The pre-defined styles are “tt”, “rm”, “sf” and “same” which all
> allow the same linebreaks but use different fonts — the first three select a specific
> font and the “same” style uses the current text font.

So you can specify the font that you want to use in `monofont` yaml key and put this `\urlstyle{tt}` just before the `# References`.

```
---
title: "Changing the fonts for hyperlink/url"
date: "2022-09-12"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
link-citations: true
link-color: red
urlcolor: blue
biblio-style: apsr
linestretch: 2
ident: True
bibliography: pkg.bib
monofont: "Comic Sans MS"
---


## Packages

- purrr [@R-purrr]
- tibble [@R-tibble]


\urlstyle{tt}

# References
```

Contents of the bib file I have used here,

**pkg.bib**

```
@Manual{R-purrr,
  title = {purrr: Functional Programming Tools},
  author = {Lionel Henry and Hadley Wickham},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 0.3.4},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=purrr},
}

@Manual{R-tibble,
  title = {tibble: Simple Data Frames},
  author = {Kirill MC<ller and Hadley Wickham},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 3.0.3},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tibble},
}
```

---

[image: changed font for urls]

---

### Option 2

You can also change the fonts for url links, by defining a new command like `\urlfont` for loading a particular font family with `\newfontfamily` (read the [`fontsepc` manual](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), p-13 to know the details) and then use that command in  `\def\UrlFont{}` to define the url font.

```
---
title: "Changing the fonts for hyperlink/url"
date: "2022-09-12"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
link-citations: true
link-color: red
urlcolor: blue
biblio-style: apsr
linestretch: 2
ident: True
bibliography: pkg.bib
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \newfontfamily\urlfont{Roboto Mono}
---


## Packages

- purrr [@R-purrr]
- tibble [@R-tibble]


\def\UrlFont{\urlfont}

# References
```

---

[image: changed url font - option 2]

---

**Do not put the commands `\urlstyle{tt}` or `\def\UrlFont{\urlfont}` in `header-includes`, because if you do that these commands will be overridden by `\urlstyle{same}` (default style set by `r-markdown`). So It's best to set these commands just before the reference section.**

Comment: Thank you for these detailed answer. One remaining question based on your comment from my side is how to change the font type. I mean I run the second option you shared with Comic Sans MS font and it worked but for other font types, it does not work. I have made a quick google search, yet because it is latex and I do not know latex much, I could not find a robust way to manipulate the font type as I wish. Therefore, if you can shed a light on this problem as well, I would appreciate that.

Comment: No worries, I just found a way to go to the font book installed on my pc and I am now able to change the font type based on the available fonts on my computer. Thank you for your time to compile this answer, I really appreciate that.